# VBScript using WMI to find out SQL Server version

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, wmi

Can anyone point me to a vbscript (using WMI) to find out the installed SQL Server version. I have a scenario where either SQL Server 2008 R2 or SQL Server 2012 could be installed on a machine.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched for such a script? And what do you want to do if *both* versions are installed (which is quite often the case), or neither version (e.g. 2005 or 2008), or no SQL Server at all?

Comment: i tried googling..could not find one.. my scenario is- one and only version would be installed. 2008 or 2012.

Comment: You couldn't have tried very hard. I googled "vbscript wmi find version of sql server" and this was the very first hit: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.scripting.wsh/MNtfPYXZhIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code in [the first Google search result here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.scripting.wsh/MNtfPYXZhIA):

```
Dim WMI, Col, Prod, Q
Set WMI = GetObject("WinMgmts:")
Q = "Select * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Vendor = " & _
    "'Microsoft Corporation' AND Name LIKE 'SQL Server%Database Engine Services'"
Set Col = WMI.ExecQuery(Q)
For Each Prod in Col
  if left(Prod.version, 3) = "11." then
    msgbox "SQL Server 2012 was found!" & vbCrLf & prod.version
  elseif left(Prod.version, 4) = "10.5" then
    msgbox "SQL Server 2008 R2 was found!" & vbCrLf & prod.version
  end if
Next
Set Col = Nothing
Set WMI = Nothing
```

Note that WMI is not the fastest way to do this. Have you considered checking the registry directly instead of going through WMI?

**UPDATE** given OP's solution using the registry instead, and with the assumption that exactly one of 2008R2 or 2012 could be installed:

```
RegKey2012 = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\" & _
             "Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\"
If RegKeyExists(RegKey2012) Then 
  WScript.StdOut.Write("2012") 
Else 
  WScript.StdOut.Write("2008R2") 
End If 

Function RegKeyExists(Key) 
  Dim oShell, entry 
  On Error Resume Next 
  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
  entry = oShell.RegRead(Key) 
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
    Err.Clear 
    RegKeyExists = False 
  Else 
    Err.Clear 
    RegKeyExists = True 
  End If 
End Function
```

Comment: thx for sorting the script out... i need to add the script in an installer, so i can use any of the methods... are you suggesting going by the registry route is better...

Comment: @Subhasis registry is probably better, yes. Not only is WMI notoriously slow from VBScript, it is also very prone to various permissions and other issues - I've come across many machines where WMI was just broken.

Comment: `If RegKeyExists("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\") Then
WScript.StdOut.Write("2012")
Else
WScript.StdOut.Write("2008R2")
End If


Function RegKeyExists(Key)
  Dim oShell, entry
  On Error Resume Next
 
  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  entry = oShell.RegRead(Key)
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    RegKeyExists = False
  Else
    Err.Clear
    RegKeyExists = True
  End If
End Function`

Comment: However, that is impossible to read as a comment. I will add it to the answer.