# How do I get the installed SQL Server version with WMI?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wmi

I'm trying to find a way to get the installed SQL Server version on some computers where I'm running my code locally.

I don't have logins for the SQL Servers, so I can't run SQL on them.
I'm aware it can be done through the registry but I have to do this using WMI.

I've read that Win32_Product can be slow to run through and when querying it with WMI Explorer it does take some time, and I read it can give errors if it takes over 30 seconds, so I'd rather find another way. These computers even include old Win2000's (and up).

Another option seems to be "SqlServiceAdvancedProperty" under "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement" as suggested here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/07/29/faq-detecting-sql-server-2005-using-wmi.aspx

But on my own computer there's two "ComputerManagement" both with numbers in the end.
"ComputerManagement10" doesn't return anything for a query on "SqlServiceAdvancedProperty" but "ComputerManagement11" does.

[image]

Can I count on the information to be present here? How do I check the right one?

Comment: Hi this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363102/vbscript-using-wmi-to-find-out-sql-server-versionmay)! may help to you.

Comment: The suggestions there is either Win32_Product or using the registry which was exactly what I wanted to avoid.